# SEO: Website html pages root in domain root or in domain subfolder?

Tags: web, seo

Is there a difference for SEO whether I put the ROOT of all the html pages of my website into the root of my domain:

`www.mywebsite.com/index.html`

or in a sub-directory of my domain:

`www.mywebsite.com/site/index.html`

In the latter case of course I would put a redirection index.html/php into the root of my domain:

`www.mywebsite.com/index.html` -> redirects to `www.mywebsite.com/site/index.html`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure terms, no.

But it can be helpful to use this URL format to categorise your site effectively.

Generally you want your homepage to be hosted on the root domain, then different categories in sub-folders.

It's the most logical way of categorising your content.

Some people may argue that the 'folder' part will let you stuff an extra keyword into the URL, but these days it's a negligible ranking factor from what I've seen.

Example of a good site structure:

- MyCakeShop.com - Homepage.
- MyCakeShop.com/aboutus - About Us.
- MyCakeShop.com/contactus - Contact Us.
- MyCakeShop.com/Cakes - A showcase of a few of the best cakes with links through to the categories.

  - MyCakeShop.com/Cakes/Birthday - A list of the birthday cakes you offer.
  - MyCakeShop.com/Cakes/Wedding - A list of the wedding cakes you offer.
- MyCakeShop.com/Biscuits - A showcase of the biscuits you offer.
- MyCakeShop.com/Offers

  - MyCakeShop.com/Offers/50%offChristmasCake
  - MyCakeShop.com/Offers/25%ValentinesDayDiscount

And so on ...

I hope that's clear!

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.